# How to add promise call inside forEach loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

```
angular.forEach(data.rows, function(value, key){
    var cell = [];
    subId = 0;
    angular.forEach(vm.tableJson, function(value1, key1){       
        if(value1.Type != 'table'){
            if(key == 0){
                vm.columns.push(value1.Name);               
            }
            cell.push(value[value1.Settings[1].Value])
        }
        else{
            reportService.getInnerTableRecords(aaa).then(function(dataRes){ //server call
                angular.forEach(dataRes.rows, function(value2, key2){
                    //some code                     
                })
            })          
        }
    });

});
```

In the above code `forEach` loop gets completed before getting response from the server.

How to make `else` case wait until response?

Thanks 
Chethan

Comment: In Javascript you can't wait. You use a callback or any other alternative.

Comment: In angularJs can  we use promise??

Comment: If you use a transcompiler you can use `await`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded. All foreach loops complete before asynchronous APIs resolve results. On the other hand, a foreach loop **can push an array of promises** that can be used to chain subsequent code:

```
var promiseArray=[];

angular.forEach(vm.tableJson, function(value1, key1){       
    if(value1.Type != 'table'){
        if(key == 0){
            vm.columns.push(value1.Name);               
        }
        cell.push(value[value1.Settings[1].Value]);
        promiseArray.push(key1);
    }
    else{
        var promise = reportService.getInnerTableRecords(aaa);
        var newPromise = promise.then(function(dataRes){ //server call
            angular.forEach(dataRes.rows, function(value2, key2){
                //some code                     
            })
            return key1;
        });
        promiseArray.push(newPromise);          
    }
});

var compositePromise = $q.all(promiseArray);

return compositePromise.then(function(keyArray) {
    console.log("Number of processed keys = " + keyArray.length);
    //
    //Do subsequent processing here
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
    throw error;
});
```

In the above example the composite promise resolves to an array of the keys for the loop. Each iteration of the loop pushes a promise to an array. The composite promise is created with [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all). The composite promise is then used to chain subsequent code.

Be sure to return promises from nested levels. Otherwise parent promises will resolve before nested levels complete.

> #### Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [--AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) to achieve that.

```
    async.mapSeries(data.rows, function(value, key, firstCallback){
        var cell = [];
        subId = 0;
        async.mapSeries(vm.tableJson, function(value1, key1, secondCallback){       
            if(value1.Type != 'table'){
                if(key == 0){
                    vm.columns.push(value1.Name);               
                }
                cell.push(value[value1.Settings[1].Value])
                secondCallback(null); // iterate next value1
            }
            else{
                reportService.getInnerTableRecords(aaa).then(function(dataRes){ //server call
                    angular.forEach(dataRes.rows, function(value2, key2){
                        //some code                     
                    });

                    secondCallback(null);// iterate next value1
                })          
            }
        }, function () {
            firstCallback(null); // all vm.tableJson completed. iterate next value of data.rows
        });

    });
```

An iterator of async.mapSeries will wait until you call `secondCallback` and only then go to the next item in `vm.tableJson`, so you can call it after receiving response from server.

Comment: The promise created by `async` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. It is likely to cause bug where changes to scope don't trigger AngularJS directives that update the DOM.